# Changing VirtualBox VM running macOS guest on macOS host to full screen?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fullscreen, macos-highsierra

How do I change the VirtualBox VM macOS High Sierra guest to full screen? When I click Full-Screen mode under the top menu bar under View it has huge black borders around the VM, while the VM is centered in the middle of the screen. I am running from a macOS High Sierra host. This is my VirtualBox version, Version 6.1.12 r139181 (Qt5.6.3). My computer is a Macbook Pro 13.3 inch.

Here is a screenshot showing the issue of the huge black border around the VM:

[image]

Does anyone know how to truly make the VM go fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

Power Off MacOS guest and click Settings of it. Go to Display tab and make sure Video memory is 128 MB or above and checkmark "Enable 3D acceleration".

Now open Command Prompt as Administrator in Host Windows system. Run `cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox"` or if the installation directory is different then use that. Then run `vboxmanage setextradata "VM_Name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1920x1080`.

If you are running Linux/MacOS Host, then directly execute the second command, no need to change directory using `cd`.

Now boot the VM and click Full Screen mode in View menu. Go to System preferences > Display in MacOS guest and set resoulution to 1920x1080.

Hope that helps

Comment: I have also provided instructions for MacOS/Linux Host, in that case run `vboxmanage` command directly without using `cd`. And VirtualBox Manager is same in Windows, Linux and MacOS.

Comment: So type this: " vboxmanage setextradata "VM_Name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1920x1080 " into the terminal?

Comment: Yes you have to type this

Comment: It didn't work. I got this error in the terminal when I type the command and pressed enter: " VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'VM_Name'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 935 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
 "

Comment: Replace 'VM_Name' with the name of MacOS guest

Comment: do I need the quotations marks around the name of the macos guest?

Comment: it's not working, but it definitely changed to more of a rectangle at launch instead of a square.

Comment: I'm on a macbook pro 13 inch by the way. does that make a difference?

Comment: Have you clicked View tab > Full Screen mode and set guest screen resolution to 1920x1080?

Comment: Yes it's in full screen mode. Do you mean set guest screen resolution in the Displays panel of System Preferences in the VM?

Comment: Yes, please do that

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: should I change the screen resolution in the terminal command to 2560x1600?

Comment: my screen on my Macbook Pro is 13.3 inches

Comment: the resolution on my macbook pro 13.3 inch is 2560x1600

Comment: I changed it to 2560x1600 and it didn't fix it. Now everything looks too small even though there is no black borders anymore

Comment: Do you have any other idea on how to possibly solve this issue?

Comment: can we move to this chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111073/room-for-arlen-and-david-anderson?

Comment: @Arlen yes feel free to move it

Comment: can you join me in the chatroom? I still haven't gotten to make the virtualbox vm scale properly in full screen mode.

Comment: Worked without an issue on Windows 10 Pro host.